# strcpy function with pointers to character array

Tags: c, pointers, stack-overflow, strcpy

In the code below the result is stack overflow. Though null character is there with both the strings, so the strcpy loop should terminate as the source string has null character. Why stack overflow occurs??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<strings.h>
int main(void) {
    char *str="Hello world";
    char *str1="Good morning";
    strcpy(str,str1);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error isn't stack overflow, but modifying a string literal.

`str` is a pointer that points to a string literal `"Hello world"`, and modifying a string literal is undefined behavior.

Change `str` to:

```
char str[100] = "Hello world";
```

Comment: Means char *str is by default const char *str?? If so why it doesnt happen in arrays of datatypes other than char?

Comment: @Siya Read [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char *s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)